How to split multiple values and relate with other fields?
I have a table with this format



H1
H2
H3




Mary
2
A,B


John
4
X,Y,U


Michael
1
P,Q,S,T,M,Z


Ana
7
L



And I'd like to convert to a table in a database form like this



H1
H2
H3




Mary
2
A


Mary
2
B


John
4
X


John
4
Y


John
4
U


Michael
1
P


Michael
1
Q


Michael
1
S


Michael
1
T


Michael
1
M


Michael
1
Z


Ana
7
L



I'm aware of TEXTSPLIT() function and I'm able to split and transpose doing this =TRANSPOSE(TEXTSPLIT(C2,",")), but then don't know how to repeat the values of column H1 and H2 when there are more than one value in H3.
Additionally, I've tried in Power Query with M code as below. After I split the column H1, I don't how to continue (I'm using Excel 365). Thanks
let
    Source = Excel.CurrentWorkbook(){[Name="Table3"]}[Content],
    #"Changed Type" = Table.TransformColumnTypes(Source,{{"H1", type text}, {"H2", Int64.Type}, {"H3", type text}}),
    #"Split Column by Delimiter" = Table.SplitColumn(#"Changed Type", "H3", Splitter.SplitTextByDelimiter(",", QuoteStyle.Csv), {"H3.1", "H3.2", "H3.3", "H3.4", "H3.5", "H3.6"})
in
    #"Split Column by Delimiter"


After you split by delimiter, you select the first two columns and then Unpivot other columns. Then you get what you need.
